# Content shifting/moving when using li:hover on navigation bar links

Tags: html, css

I have an issue whereby the content on the page is shifted downwards or to the right. This happens when using li:hover to add a border-bottom or font-weight: 700; to my navigation links.

I'm trying to add some styling to the navigation links when the user is hovering over them. However, when the style is applied content on the page is shifted/moved.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

```css
/* GLOBAL */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Hevletica", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

header, .container, footer{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

div.banner img {
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
}

/* NAV BAR */
.list-reset a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: #000;
}

nav.main-nav ul {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.main-nav li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

li a:hover {
  /*border-bottom: 3px solid #FF0000;*/
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">

    <title>Practice</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <header>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul class="list-reset">
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="banner">
        <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <h1>Lorem!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="newsletter">
        <h1>Newsletter</h1>
        <form class="newsletter-form">
          <label for="email"></label>
          <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
          <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- CONTAINER END -->
  </body>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; fname sname 2017</p>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: when adding border you increase height and thus the shift .. isntead make the border already present and transparent and change only colore on hover

Comment: so simply add this to `a` `border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;`